# Distinct concat two IEnumerables and flag if it came from list B

Tags: c#, linq, merge, ienumerable

Wood for the trees moment I'm sure.

```
var dateListA = new List<DateTime>();
var dateListB = new List<DateTime>();

for (var date = DateTime.Parse("01-Dec-2013"); date <= DateTime.Parse("08-Dec-2013"); date = date.AddDays(1))
    dateListA.Add(date);

for (var date = DateTime.Parse("05-Dec-2013"); date <= DateTime.Parse("10-Dec-2013"); date = date.AddDays(1))
    dateListB.Add(date);

var results = distinct_Merge_Of_dateListA_And_dateListB_But_With_New_WasInListB_Boolean_Property => new { Date, WasInListB };

foreach (var result in results)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", result.Date, result.WasInListB);
}
```

Expected output

> ```
> 01-Dec-2013 No
> 02-Dec-2013 No
> 03-Dec-2013 No
> 04-Dec-2013 No
> 05-Dec-2013 Yes
> 06-Dec-2013 Yes
> 07-Dec-2013 Yes
> 08-Dec-2013 Yes
> 09-Dec-2013 Yes
> 10-Dec-2013 Yes
> ```

I'm trying two merge to lists but indicate in the final list (with a boolean) if the result was included in list B. Any hints on how to do is are appreciated.

Comment: could a date be found in both?

Comment: @AFrieze : Yes it could. Both lists could potentially have the exact same dates and therefore should result the distinct dates with WasInListB set to true in all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
var newInA = dateListA.Except(dateListB);
var results = newInA
                 .Select(d => new { Date = d, WasInListB = false })
                 .Concat(dateListB.Select(d => new { Date = d, WasInListB = true }));
```

This will give you the results you listed.  It lists items that are only found in A first, then all items from B.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps,
Just tested and I believe this does just what you are looking for...although a more efficient method may be possible.

```
var dateData = dateListB.Select(x => new { Date = x, InB = true }).Union(dateListA.Except(dateListB).Select(x => new { Date = x, InB = false })).ToList();
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary. Classic bin approach:

```
var results = new Dictionary<DateTime,bool>();
foreach( var date in dateListA )
 results[date] = false;
foreach( var date in dateListB )
 results[date] = true;
foreach (var result in results)
 System.Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", result.Key, result.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to discard all dates from B that are also in A, you could achive this with a GroupBy, then selecting only the first element from each group (which will be from A if there are two, since A was added first

```
 dateListA.Select(a => new { Date = a, FromB = false })
         .Concat(dateListB.Select(b => new { Date = b, FromB = true })
         .GroupBy(x=>x.Date)
         .Select(gp=> gp.First());
```

If you want to know whether an item occured in A and in B, you could use

```
 dateListA.Select(a => new { Date = a, FromB = false })
         .Concat(dateListB.Select(b => new { Date = b, FromB = true })
         .GroupBy(x=>x.Date)
         .Select(gp=> new {Date = gp.Key, FromA = gp.Any(x=>!x.FromB), FromB = gp.Any(x=>x.FromB));
```